# How to create couchbase full text search index alias using the api

Tags: couchbase

When creating the full text search index using admin interface, i can use 
"Show curl command to modify this index definition" option to get a curl command.

[image]

like this one :

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -u Administrator:password
http://localhost:8094/api/index/idx_order_customer -d \
'{definition body}'
```

is there a way to create the index alias also using curl option.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It's a PUT to the same endpoint. Example:

`PUT /api/index/{indexName}`

With a similar JSON body to your example. In fact, when you are creating a new index, an "Index Definition Preview" will show up in the Couchbase Server UI with the JSON body.

[image]

For more information, check out the documentation: [Couchbase REST API Documentation - FTS indexes](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/rest-api/rest-fts-indexing.html#p-api-index-name)

Comment: Thanks i didn't pay attention that part